# Attach a file to sp_send_dbmail from C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm currently developing an asp.net page where a custom PDF is generated, and then needs to be emailed to customers.  Currently we call the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure to send email, but we haven't had to attach files to it yet.

I've looked all around, but it's looking more and more like `sp_send_dbmail` can only send attachments that are stored within the database, or on the machine that runs the server.  This would be through the `@file_attachments` parameter. The other option would be using the `@query` and `@attach_query_result_as_file` parameters.

Here is the code we currently use to send emails:

```
public static void sendEmail(string emailAddress, string body)
{

    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail");

    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@profile_name", DbType.String, "Profile");
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@recipients", DbType.String, emailAddress);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@subject", DbType.String, "Report: ");
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@body", DbType.String, body);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@body_format", DbType.String, "HTML");

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

}
```

I've tried adding

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@file_attachments", DbType.Binary, attachment);
```

and

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@query", DbType.String, "SELECT " + attachment + " AS 'attachment'");
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@attach_query_result_as_file", DbType.Boolean, true);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@query_attachment_filename", DbType.String, "pdf");
```

with `byte[] attachment` representing the pdf file. Neither has worked.

I've also tried giving `@file_attachments` the direct path to the pdf, but the pdf is on my local machine, not the SQL server, so it can't find it.

Comment: Why not use .NET's [built in SMTP client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You can use .net [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class, avoiding to set mail profiles in your server.

Comment: I've never heard of this built in client.  I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: SmtpClient does what I need.  My company has one coded using gmail in a different project. Thanks for pointing me toward it.